# OAuth 2 authentication in Chrome extension using Google API Client Libriary

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension which access Google Drive in which OAuth 2 authentication request is carried out by using Google API Client Libriary for javascript. My extenstion was already registered in Google Developers Console.

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
},
```

**background.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="google_auth/initiation.js"></script>
```

**initiation.js**

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'MY_CLIENT_ID';
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';

jQuery(window).load(function() {
   gapi.auth.authorize({
     client_id: CLIENT_ID,
     scope: SCOPES,
     immediate: false
  }, function(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
           window.alert('Auth was successful!');
        } else {
           window.alert('Auth was not successful');
        }
     }
   );
 });
```

When the extension is loaded or reloaded in the browser, a popup appears and I receive a response message from Google:

That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

Application: MyExtension

Actually, I'm wondering if choosing Google API Client Library for my Chrome extension is right and there's any thing missing wrong with my implemention.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but if your initiation.js is verbatim. You should replace 'MY_CLIENT_ID' and CLIENT_ID with the client ID that you received when registering your app with Google here https://console.developers.google.com/

it looks like this: 

`858545004388-tlfkq1hfdbuiductlb0qdvjds4s949gt.apps.googleusercontent.com`

That's what Error: invalid_client is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

> Web authentication protocols utilize HTTP features, but Chrome Apps
>   run inside the app container; they don’t load over HTTP and can’t
>   perform redirects or set cookies.

use Google identity https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Comment: The chrome.identity API is limited to a single account with which a user is signed into Chrome, while Google API Client Library allows to authenticate with any Google account.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, The google js api client will not work for chrome extensions, And the only way to use Gapi would be to ship the whole js file itself with the bundle as external scripts are not allowed on the manifest v3. You would be better off simply calling the endpoints by yourselves and getting out of the mess.